# How to create multi-page application using html and Jquery

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, xml, cordova

I am working on a native application for iphone. This application read content from XML. I have many links and button which read content from XML.
Everything is working great except back button. Since, I have created a Single Page application therefore back button is not working. I thought to convert this application into multipage. But I am not sure what is the best way to do so using jquery, XML and html. I have read the xml and put all the values in the arrays and dealing with array.

I am reading XML using

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var meetingName = [];
                var buildingName = [];
                var floorInfo = [];
                var officeContact = [];
                var roomEmail = [];
                var capacity = [];
                var phoneNotes = [];
                var pdfName = [];
                var pdfRoomName=[];
                var myHTMLOutput = '';
                var indexVal='';
                $('#menu').hide();
                var location='';

                // Open the IMRM.xml file
                $.get("xml/IMRM.xml",{},function(xml) {

                    // Build an HTML string
                    // Run the function for each Room tag in the XML file
                    $('Room',xml).each(function(i) {
                        meetingName[i] = $(this).find("meetingRoomName").text();
                        buildingName[i] = $(this).find("buildingName").text();
                        floorInfo[i] = $(this).find("floorInfo").text();
                        officeContact[i] = $(this).find("officeContact").text();
                        roomEmail[i] = $(this).find("roomEmail").text();
                        capacity[i] = $(this).find("capacity").text();
                        phoneNotes[i] = $(this).find("phoneNotes").text();
                        pdfName[i] = $(this).find("pdfName").text();
                        pdfRoomName[i] = $(this).find("pdfRoomName").text();
                    }
                );
                document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Muncipal Building";               

                //Capture button click and show information for each room
                $(".left").click(function() {
                    buttonClick($(this).attr("data-value"));
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div id="wrapper" class="imr">    
            <div data-role="page" data-theme="bu" id="imr">      
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="bk" class="ui-header" role="banner">
                    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-add-back-btn="true"  data-back-btn-text="Back" data-theme="bk" class="header-btn-bk back-btn" id="back"></a>
                    <h1 class="font-narrow font-bold imr-header-title" id= "title"></h1>
                    <a href= "Terms_of_use.html" data-theme="bk" class="header-btn-bk info-btn"></a>
                </div>          

                <div data-role="content" data-theme="bu" class="content">  
                    <div id="information" >
                        <!-- <a class = "policy" href= "Terms_of_use.html" style="display:inline"> Terms of Use </a> -->
                    </div>            

                    <div id= "main" style="display:none">
                        <div id= "inputArea">
                            <input type="text" id ="roomInput" /> <input id= "cancel" type="button" value ="Cancel" disabled/>
                            <ul id= "auto_suggest" data-role="listview" data-insert="true"> </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="floor-btn">    
                            <a href= "#" data-role="button" class="left" data-ajax= "false" data-value="1"> 1 <span class="floor-btn-bgtxt"></span></a>
                            <a href= "#" data-role="button" class="right" data-ajax= "false" data-value="2"> 2 <span class="floor-btn-bgtxt"></span></a>
                            <a href= "#" data-role="button"class="left" data-ajax= "false" data-value="3"> 3 <span class="floor-btn-bgtxt"></span></a>
                            <a href= "#" data-role="button" class="right" data-ajax= "false" data-value="4"> 4 <span class="floor-btn-bgtxt"></span></a>
                            <a href= "#" data-role="button"class="left" data-ajax= "false" data-value="5"> 5 <span class="floor-btn-bgtxt"></span></a>
                            <a href= "#" data-role="button" class="right" data-ajax= "false" data-value="6"> 6 <span class="floor-btn-bgtxt"></span></a>
                            <a href= "#" data-role="button"class="left" data-ajax= "false" data-value="7"> 7 <span class="floor-btn-bgtxt"></span></a>
                            <a href= "#"  data-role="button" class="right" data-ajax= "false" data-value="8"> 8 <span class="floor-btn-bgtxt"></span></a>
                            <a href= "#" data-role="button"class="left" data-ajax= "false" data-value="9"> 9 <span class="floor-btn-bgtxt"></span></a>
                            <a href= "#" data-role="button" class="right" data-ajax= "false" data-value="10"> 10 <span class="floor-btn-bgtxt"></span></a>
                            <a href= "#" data-role="button"class="left" data-ajax= "false" data-value="11"> 11 <span class="floor-btn-bgtxt"></span></a>
                            <a href= "#" data-role="button" class="right" data-ajax= "false" data-value="12"> 12 <span class="floor-btn-bgtxt"></span></a>
                            <a href= "#" data-role="button" class="left" data-ajax= "false" data-value="B"> B <span class="floor-btn-bgtxt"></span></a>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div><!-- End: content -->  
            </div><!-- End: page -->
        </div><!-- End: wrapper -->
    </body>   
</html>
```

In this I am reading xml and saving each nodes to an array. In HTML I have few buttons(Named from 1 to 12), autocomplete text box, links which gets the content on their click from those array in JS.  This all is happening in one HTML page and using one XML page.  Now, if I click on Button 1 and which is showing a list of links and on the link if I click it gives some information.

Enclosed please see the structure:
index.html (have)--> Button1,button2,button3, etc (Click on Button1)-->Show a list of links a1,a2,a3 etc (Click on a1)--> Shows some information.

All this is happening on the index.html page and showing or hiding content accordingly.  Since, it is just one page and there is no change in the URL therefore back button is not working. I want to show the last state on clicking on the back button. For Example: on last information page if I click back button it should take me to the list of links page.

Because of that back issue, I thought to use multiple page application. But it is reading everything from XML and therefore I am not sure what is the best way to read XML on different html page. I found different ways like using cookies or use JSON to get the values. But I am not sure if it is good to use any one of them for iphone native app.

Please suggest me what is the best way to make my application as multi-page application. I am fairly new to jquery.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: This question is overly broad and does not properly describe how you built it in the first place, therefore no one can really suggest how to do it differently.

Comment: what do you mean by multipage application? its all your wish to add one or multiple pages in your application. And navigation from one page to another is all depends upon your application flow. Please describe your problem/question in a better way to get better response.

Comment: I have updated my question with my code. Hope this will give some more clarity.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have handle the issue by using cookies.
I have saving all states in cookies and calling all those states on back button click.

So, I didn't need to make my application as multiple page application.

Thank you so much though !!